# Popup dialog in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I used jQuery mobile and added popup on leftmost button but the popup window is not centered as to screen it gets left padding more.

Popup dialog is not centered in portrait mode in android mode I have used the code from this link to generate popup dialog button from [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear as to what problem you're having, but to center the dialog on the window, just use `data-position-to="window"` like this:

```
<a href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">

<div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow">
    <p>I am positioned to the window.</p>
</div>
```